# EF Core 7 Moving connection string out of DbContext class

Tags: blazor-server-side, ef-core-7.0

Trying to move my connection string out of `dbcontext` as VS warns about leaving it there. I have found some other posts, but most were older versions of EF Core, with special circumstances. Things work when `OnConfiguring` is not commented out.

I have set up the service in Program.cs as such:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

I have the connection string set up in the `appsettings.json` per the docs:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source= ... "
  }
}
```

Here is my dbcontext class:

```
public partial class ParaisoContext : DbContext
{
    public ParaisoContext()
    {
    }

    public ParaisoContext(DbContextOptions<ParaisoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Rentals> Rentals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Units> Units { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    //{
    //    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    //    {
    //        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source= ....");
    //    }
    //}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Rentals>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.RenterType).IsFixedLength();
            entity.Property(e => e.UnitId).IsFixedLength();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Units>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Unit).IsFixedLength();
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use DbContextFactory.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ParaisoContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection"));
```